# Markov-Switching E-GARCH with R

Tags: volatility, r, garch, markov-switching

I am looking for a **R** library for modeling a **Markov-Switching E-GARCH** process.

In other questions at *StackExchange* related to **GARCH** models, the package **rugarch** is often mentionned. Do you recommend it in my case?

I would like that **R** library I am seeking had the following features:

- allows to observe/control the volatility term structure
- allows to impose long-term volatility
- has calibration routines
- includes forecasting procedures

In fact, I would like to carry out a volatility analysis work *à la* Carole Alexander, as described in her book [Market Risk Analysis Volume II: Practical Financial Econometrics](http://www.carolalexander.org/mra_vol_2.html).

Thank you.

Comment: I don't think Markov-switching GARCH models are implemented in R as of now. "rugarch" is indeed a good package for univariate GARCH (and ARFIMA) models, and "rmgarch" is a useful package for multivariate GARCH models, but there is no Markov switching there. What do you mean exactly by "impose long-term volatility"?

Comment: @RichardHardy: Now they are, please see my answer below: http://quant.stackexchange.com/a/33609/12

Comment: @vonjd, thank you, it will be interesting to take a look.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is now a package for that: The MSGARCH package, you can find it on [CRAN](https://CRAN.R-project.org/package=MSGARCH).

You can find an exhaustive vignette here:

[David Ardia, Keven Bluteau, Kris Boudt, Denis-Alexandre Trottier: Markov-Switching GARCH Models in R: The MSGARCH Package (2016)](https://papers.ssrn.com/sol3/papers.cfm?abstract_id=2845809)

**Abstract**

> Markov-switching GARCH models have become popular to model the
>   structural break in the conditional variance dynamics of financial
>   time series. In this paper, we describe the R package MSGARCH which
>   implements Markov-switching GARCH-type models very effficiently by
>   using C object-oriented programming techniques. It allows the user to
>   perform simulations as well as Maximum Likelihood and Bayesian
>   estimation of a very large class of Markov-switching GARCH-type
>   models. Risk management tools such as Value-at-Risk and
>   Expected-Shortfall calculations are available. An empirical
>   illustration of the usefulness of the R package MSGARCH is presented.

For modelling EGARCH you set `model = "eGARCH"` in the `create.spec` function (see p. 2 in the abovementioned vignette).